# How do I escape an '@' in GitLab Markdown?

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I often use '@' in directory names (because names that start with that character are sorted before names that start with a letter or number).

But if I try to write a path containing a name with that character in Markdown in GitLab it is rendered as a 'mention' (of a user or group). I don't want that. Presumably GitLab might also actually notify the user or group too – I definitely don't want that!

So how can I quote or escape the '@' so that it's rendered normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine tags for an HTML `span` with the relevant HTML character entity:

```
*C:\\<span>&#64;</span>code\my-project*
*~/<span>&#64;</span>code/my-project*
```

See:

- [Character Entity Reference Chart – HTML5 Reference – W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all directory names in code spans (single back-ticks). While this is bordering on opinion, many would argue that directory names (paths, URLs, etc.) should be marked up as "code". And if you do wrap them in code spans, then they will not be treated as a "mention".

```
A Windows path (`C:\\@code\my-project`) and a posix path (`~/@code/my-project`).
```

The above example gets rendered as...

> A Windows path (`C:\\@code\my-project`) and a posix path (`~/@code/my-project`).

Comment: I used to insist (mostly in my own head) that paths are 'not code' and thus shouldn't be formatted as such, but I've actually come around to both formatting them as code and thinking of them as 'code-like'.